# Create PHP Code Encryptor

Tags: php, encryption

Here goes my question I just started to investigate some of the php's methods to create Encrypted strings , and surprisingly I found quite alot .

Md5 , Sha1 , base64 , salts, str_replace(which isnt even of an encryptor ) etc etc. But here is my Real Question - Can i create similar to those CODE encryptors. Atm i can convert only strings,is it possable  encrypt my whole PHP source code then decrypt it (with my own enccryptor) and  run the Code  . Sth like that - . Most of those i found are easily reversable.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Md5 , Sha1 , base64 is not encryption...

Comment: The problem is not if you can, I think it is more like when, and maybe why. Please explain it a lit better.

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè: base64 is.. OP: search and thee shall find, PHP code encryption/obfuscation is asked for quite a lot.

Comment: Base 64 is like 10 secs from decoding !

Comment: Anyways use bytecode encoder like ioncube, Zend Guard or SourceGuardian, code obfuscation does not work despite what the authors says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in "encrypting" your code. Don't make too much a deal of it. There are billions of lines of freely available PHP code already. Anyone could have any code they want. So, just take it easy and put your efforts in **improving** your code instead of encoding it.

Comment: I am going to sell that , I forgot to mention that above. And i dont really want it to be stolen or re-sold to otherppl !

Comment: Frankly, I don't think your code is worth stealing it.

Comment: The best safeguard against code theft isn't obfuscation or encryption, it's a legal license that you're prepared to defend

Comment: How did you figure !? Licenses - i wont go there - atm !

Comment: How do I figure? Experience, knowing how much aggravation and strife are caused to legitimate users by encrypted code compared to cost in defending licensed code against piracy

Comment: Ok let me put it that way ! Here is simple example of what i want to do . <?php function enc($string) { str_replace('a','1', $string).... i've got some enc methods here ..... echo $string } enc('text'); ?>. I want to encode the "text" as it is in php code and then when i implement it in my decoder to decode it and RUN it . How can i RUN it when it gets decoded ? Say like echo (<?php echo 123; ?>); -> to run as normal php code in browser and show me 123.